# Html.fromHtml problem

Tags: android, html, image, insert, drawable

I'm using Html.fromhtml to insert image in an editText ... but the instead of displaying the image, it displays [obj] " the text obj inside a square"
what could be the problem ??
This is the imageGetter

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.e11);
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
 return d;
             }
          };
```

This is the code line:

```
CharSequence cs = 
Html.fromHtml("<img src='" +getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.e11)+ "'/>"
,imageGetter, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to add a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your `imageGetter` instance is not doing the correct thing. Where is it trying to retrieve the images from and what does it look like?

Comment: the image i want to retrive is located in Drawable folder ... (local resource)
it is called e11.png

Comment: where is the problem, please ?

Comment: Where is the code for your `imageGetter` instance? That is the problem: it is not retrieving the correct image.

Comment: ok I will edit the post .. and add the function there .. ok ?

Comment: by the way .. i tried it in application with editText .. and i was able to see the image in the editText 
buttttttt when i use the same code in softkeyboard application 
i see the obj squares ...

Comment: Might be that the soft keyboard runs in a process that doesn't have access to your application's resources?

Comment: this code is inside the softkeyboard class
and the images are in the res folder of the same application