# How to get HTML ImageGetter to work properly

Tags: android, string, image, path, html-parsing

I have implemented an ImageGetter within an Html.fromHtml method by reading the following posts: [Html.fromHtml problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138636/html-fromhtml-problem), and [Html.ImageGetter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792604/html-imagegetter).
Here is the code with the ImageGetter:

```
if (mItem != null) {
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exercise_detail))
                .setText(Html.fromHtml(mItem.description, new ImageGetter(){ 

                @Override public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                      Drawable drawFromPath;
                      int path =
                            ExerciseDetailFragment.this.getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable",
                                    "com.package.ChaitanyaVarier.mytrainer2go");
                      drawFromPath = (Drawable) ExerciseDetailFragment.this.getResources().getDrawable(path);
                      drawFromPath.setBounds(0, 0, drawFromPath.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                         drawFromPath.getIntrinsicHeight());
                      return drawFromPath;
                   }
                }, null));

    }
```

Here is the HTML within a string called description (**inside another activity file**) that becomes the path:

```
<img src =\"file:///android_asset/img/situp1.png\">
```

I have put an image named situp1.png inside a folder named img which is inside the assets folder.

The problem is that the path within my HTML is not getting parsed properly, and the app crashes when I try to load the item containing the image. I know for a fact that the string within the img tag is getting recognized, and I have verified this through debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was to change

```
<img src =\"file:///android_asset/img/situp1.png\">
```

to

```
<img src=\"situp1\">
```

as it was already in the resource folder and hence a drawable.

I also had to change

```
ExerciseDetailFragment.this.getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", "com.package.ChaitanyaVarier.mytrainer2go");
```

to

```
ExerciseDetailFragment.this.getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", "com.ChaitanyaVarier.mytrainer2go");
```

A rather silly problem I had, just had to understand the code a little better.